# R ggplot2: Plotting two graphs on top of each other

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with a y axis consisting of gene names. 
[image: Current graph]

However, I also want another axis on the right side of the graph to display the category that the gene belongs to. I made a separate ggplot that looks like this

[image: Second ggplot]

I want to overlay them so that it looks like the first plot has two y-axis. Is there a way that I can graph them simultaneously on top of each other?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide reproducible example and the code you have used thus far

Comment: You could do it in one plot using sec_axis()

Comment: See tstenner's answer at the dupe for a solution with the current version.

Comment: have a look at this: https://rpubs.com/MarkusLoew/226759

Comment: There is no need for 2nd axis. Some options: Prefix the grouping on gene names with `paste`. Use `geom_facet` on groups. Use `col/fill` argument on `geom_tiles/rectangle`.

Comment: I have tried doing a secondary y axis, but it seems that sec.axis functionality only applies to scale_y_continuous. However, my graph is scale_y_discrete. Also, I'm not looking to facet my plot.